# Definitions of computer forensics and information security

Tags: forensics

I'm about to do my master and I need to make a decision on what course I should take now I have two options either **computer forensics** or **information security**

What I want to know is:

- What is the difference/gap between these two disciplines?
- Are they somehow related so if I take any of them I can still go and practice the other field - in case I wanted to change my job field?

Comment: Please gain 20 reputation points and feel free to ask this question in the [DMZ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz), this is not a career advice forum.

Comment: user2309720, this hint (-1) was not mine :|

Comment: @DeerHunter ops...the hint I meant it for the comment not the -1  as that should be called hint it's a gun shoot :-P

Comment: user2309720, have you tried comparing the outlines of the two courses? Have you done any other research on the issue? If you have please edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: well yes I did and there's a difference on the curriculum and at the mean time I doing my researches on that and this question is part of this work....

Comment: Briefly, InfoSec is the preparation and maintenance of defensive measures against threats. Forensics is the investigation and response to a successful attack. A forensic investigator provides legally admissible evidence to the prosecution, and they also provide intelligence to the InfoSec teams enabling them to repair their defenses.  The two fields are closely related, and it is valuable for one to understand the other.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest seeing the following "[Technical Certification Roadmap](http://infiltrated.net/TechnicalSecurityRoadmap.html)"

The answer to your questions are enough to fill a book. The two (infosec and forensics) are like apples and oranges. Both fruits, each different. In forensics, depending on what you are doing, there could be life and liberty at hand if you are performing forensics with the ultimate route being, a court case. In infosec, same applies (slightly): life, privacy. (If you're working at say a SCADA based environment, one mishap could endanger life, if you're working in the medical arena, privacy comes first).

Aside from these two huge gaps, it works best to get a feel for both as they complement one another however, they are both extremely different. The companies hiring for these roles also hugely differ. For example, many huge law firms hire forensics experts for the sake of having talent on-hand to analyze cases, but have no true blue infosec program. Some Fortune N companies hire strong infosec teams and lack/substitute forensics with "incident responders." In forensics, chain of command, evidence, spoilation, etc., come first. In infosec, this is barely an afterthought.

Personally, I feel its best to understand both realms although they in themselves are VERY BROAD fields. Hence me posting the roadmap. The roadmap linked, shows the variations of "infosec" as there are many: application security, network security, infrastructure security, web security, SCADA based security. Same applies for forensics: E-Discovery, Incident Response, Privacy, Legal based (going to a trial).